# Swift : Get the values of first cell and and multiply with value of cell two

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am doing an app form and i want to get values of textfields. The problem is how to get the values of first cell and  multiply with valueField of second cell.
All of them are made with costum cell except the first cell and the result cell that are from eureka forms.

there are two files that i have used :

```
ViewController.swift


import UIKit
import Eureka

class ViewController: FormViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var rules = RuleSet<String>()

    form +++ Section("EINGABESUMME BRUTTO (EXXL MWST)")

    {
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }

        }
        <<< DecimalRow(){ row in
           //row.value = 0
            row.title = " "
            row.tag = "MyRowTag"
            row.placeholder="0.00"
            row.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.eingabessumeBrutto.rawValue
            }

            .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                cell.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)


    }


    form +++ Section("ZIEL-DB PROJEKT BRUTTO")
    {
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }
        }

        <<< KalkulationRow { row in
            //row.tag = "MyRowTag1"
            row.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.zielBrutto.rawValue

            //             row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"

           // row.value = User(percentage: 45, value: 45)
    }


    form +++ Section("RABATT")
    {
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }

        }
        <<< KalkulationRow { row in
            row.tag = "MyRowTag2"
  //          row.cell.percentageField.tag = KalkulationTag.rabatt.rawValue

            }
        .cellUpdate{cell, row in
            //print("sevgjan")

    }


    form +++ Section("SKONTO")
    {
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }

        }

        <<< IntRow(){
            $0.title = "Tage:"
            $0.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.tage.rawValue
            $0.add(rule: RuleRequired())
            $0.tag = "tage"


            }

            .cellUpdate { cell, row in

                cell.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)


        }
        <<< KalkulationRow { row in
         row.cell.valueField.tag = KalkulationTag.skonto.rawValue
            row.cell.percentageField.tag = KalkulationTag.skontoPercent.rawValue
          //row.cell.percentageField.text = "54"
    }
      .cellUpdate { cell, row in
    if cell.tag == KalkulationTag.skonto.rawValue {

        print("rijiljgjd554")
    }
    }
    form +++ Section("DIVERSE ABZUGE")
    {
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }

        }
        <<< KalkulationRow { row in
            //row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"
            row.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.diverse.rawValue
    }



    form +++ Section("EINGABESSUME NETTO")
    {
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }

        }
        <<< DecimalRow(){
            $0.title = " "
         // $0.value = 0
            $0.placeholder = "0.00"
            $0.placeholderColor = UIColor.green
            $0.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.result.rawValue


            }
            .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                cell.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
                cell.textField?.textColor = UIColor.green
               // cell.textField?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }



    form +++ Section("ZIEL-DB PROJEKT NETTO")
    {
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }

        }

        <<< KalkulationRow { row in
        row.cell.tag = KalkulationTag.zielNetto.rawValue
            //row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"
    }

}
}
```

and here is KalkulationCell.swift

```
import Foundation
import Eureka


// You can also map to Int
enum KalkulationTag: Int {
    case zielBrutto = 10
    case rabatt = 120
    case skonto = 11
    case skontoPercent = 43
    case diverse = 12
    case eingabessumeBrutto = 188
    case zielNetto = 14
    case result = 17
    case tage = 122
}


final class KalkulationCell: Cell<User>, CellType , UITextFieldDelegate{



    @IBOutlet var percentageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var valueField: UITextField!

    required init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        // we do not want our cell to be selected in this case. If you use such a cell in a list then you might want to change this.
        percentageField.delegate = self
        valueField.delegate = self
        selectionStyle = .none


        // 5percentageField.text = "25.00"
        // define fonts for our labels
        percentageField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        valueField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)

        percentageField.textColor=UIColor.black
        // percentageField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        // specify the desired height for our cell
        //height = { return 94 }

        // set a light background color for our cell
        // backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.984, green:0.988, blue:0.976, alpha:1.00)
    }

    override func update() {
        super.update()


        // get the value from our row

        guard let user = row.value else { return }
        //
        percentageField.text = user.percentage.description
        valueField.text = user.value.description
    }



    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

       calculate()
        //skonto()
        //res()
    }

//    func skonto(){
//        if (self.tag == KalkulationTag.skonto.rawValue) != nil{
//            print("testtt")
//
//        }
//
//
//
//    }
    func res(){
        if (self.tag == KalkulationTag.eingabessumeBrutto.rawValue){
      print("rezultati")

        }
    }

    func calculate(){

        let row: DecimalRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag: "MyRowTag"))!

        let perqindja = Double(percentageField.text!)
        let vlera = Double(valueField.text!)
          if let vlera1 = row.value{

                if perqindja != nil {

                    let kosto = (row.value)!*perqindja!*0.01
                    valueField.text  = kosto.description
                    let exclamationMark: Character = "%"
                    percentageField.text?.append(exclamationMark)
                    valueField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                }else if vlera != nil {

                    let kosto1 = round((vlera!/(row.value)!)*100)

                    percentageField.text  = kosto1.description
                    let exclamationMark: Character = "%"
                    percentageField.text?.append(exclamationMark)
                    percentageField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                }

            }
            else{


            }

    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


        if let text = textField.text,
            !text.isEmpty {
            textField.text?.removeLast()
            //valueField.text?.removeAll()
        }
       calculate()
       // skonto()
        res()
        return formViewController()?.textInputShouldBeginEditing(textField, cell: self) ?? true
    }

}


struct User: Equatable {

    var percentage: String
    var value: String

}
func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.percentage == rhs.percentage
}


final class KalkulationRow: Row<KalkulationCell>, RowType {
    required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellProvider = CellProvider<KalkulationCell>(nibName: "KalkulationCell")
    }
}
```

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN5IP.png)

Comment: What is the issue? Currently you are able to get the first cell value and in your custom cell you can use that so whats is issue here?

Comment: Issue is  Because i can not make calculations so i can not get the first value with the second value: i used this code: func res(){ let row: DecimalRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag: "MyRowTag"))!;  let row1: DecimalRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag: "result"))!; let perqindja = Double(percentageField.text!)
        let vlera = Double(valueField.text!)
        print(formCell()?.tag)
         if (formCell()!.tag == KalkulationTag.result.rawValue){
            let test = (row.value)!-vlera!
            row1.value = test
            print(row1.value)
    }